# Android + Parse get objectId from Query

Tags: java, android, parsing

This is probably a very basic question but i'm very new to android.

How would I get the objectId of the returned item from this query?

```js
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("GameScore");
query.whereEqualTo("playerName", "Dan Stemkoski");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> scoreList, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + scoreList.size() + " scores");
        } else {
            Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get object id from `scoreList` you can iterate that list and use `getObjectId` method.

Example like this

```
for(ParseObject obj : scoreList)
{
String id = obj.getObjectId;
}
```